# How to create Session Id for every Login in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I am new to MVC, I want to get new sessionId for everylogin, for that i am getting like

```
     string sessionId=HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
```

But, it is generating same sessionid for every login.

I have used to remove or clear session like below:

```
        Session.Abandon();
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Session.Clear();
```

But there is no change in genereating sessionid for every login.
Is there any alternative to create new sessionId for every login?

Comment: whats the significations to you for getting a unique sessionID for every login? you shouldn't worry about that at all...

Comment: for some requirements in my project. I need to get sessionid!

Comment: requirements are terrible in such a case.... they shouldn't depend on sessionID. what exactly is the requirement? you need to correct this before moving onwards. also, take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx and this: http://forums.asp.net/post/7504.aspx

Comment: Yes I do, requirement is if a user logged in with his credentials , and another user should not login until first user log out , straightly preventing multi-user login.

Comment: sessionID is not reliable for such a thing. you need some other means to truly determine this case. Also, read this about sessionID: http://forums.asp.net/post/7504.aspx - you are most likely using the same browser session to check your session id.

Comment: is there any option to generate new sessionId for every time?

Comment: No. the ASP.NET engine does this - users should never do this for many reasons. Only other way is to download the ASP.NET MVC source code and modify it and use it to your needs. But you will be shooting yourself in the foot by doing these changes.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Do you not leave the newly logged in user open to session fixation attacks? if a previous user has made a note of the session Id, they can hijack the session when the new user has logged in (assuming authentication/authorization have not been properly implemented).

Comment: not sure I follow. I understand what you are saying about the session fixation attacks but don't quite understand your comment.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas So I am on computer A, I observer that the session ID is 1234. I go away from computer A and observer another user log into a website. I set my session ID on computer B to 1234 and go to the same website. If the website is not properly secured, I will be presented with the other user's data. Having a new session ID will prevent this (yes I know it can be prevented with proper authentication/authorization but some of us have paranoid clients and see having the same ID as a massive security hole).

Comment: Right - sure. I agree but this shouldn't be used to ignore the whole authorization and authentication process either. Even creating a new sessionID will result, at some point, on generating a previous generated sessionID but chances of this happening quite often are VERY low.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I agree it is not a replacement for authorization, but clients have read up on session fixation and panic when they see the session ID not changing! I'm not sure session fixation/session hijacking is even an issue if security is implemented properly?

Comment: Yes it is - you just use the the .ASPXAUTH cookie instead of ASP.NET_SessionId.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got better solution to create new session id like

```
SessionIDManager manager = new SessionIDManager();
string newSessionId =  manager.CreateSessionID(HttpContext.Current);
```

above code helped me.

Comment: httpcontextbase does not contain defintion for current error is throwing

Answer (score 13):

Try this when you abandon session/Logout:

```
Session.Abandon();
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
```

By clearing out that cookie, a new session with a new session ID will be created after second login.

Answer (score 0):

Session identifiers for abandoned or expired sessions are recycled by default. That is, if a request is made that includes the session identifier for an expired or abandoned session, a new session is started using the same session identifier. You can disable this by setting `regenerateExpiredSessionId` attribute of the [sessionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/h6bb9cz9(v%3Dvs.100)) configuration element to true.
You can refer to [HttpSessionState.Abandon Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Framework 4.0 this worked for me:

```
using System.Web;
...
string sid = HttpContext.Session.SessionID;
```

Comment: Your answer is telling you to get `SessionID`. Friend wants to create `SessionID`.

Answer (score -5):

Just create maybe a table (or another column to user table), and logged when user is inside the website.
Something like a flag to determine that a user is currently login
Do some job to check and signout a user for some time, admin supposedly can manually kill the session.